# Maven build issue with codehaus package

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am trying to build the ear using Maven and received the following error.

```
   [INFO] SASC .............................................. SUCCESS [10.134s]
[INFO] SASC-war .......................................... SUCCESS [41.967s]
[INFO] SASC-ear .......................................... FAILURE [2.764s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 55.162s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Dec 15 10:52:50 CST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 9M/93M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.6:generate-application-xml (default-generate-application-xml) on project SASC-ear: Execution default-generate-application-xml of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.6:generate-application-xml failed: A required class was missing while executing org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.6:generate-application-xml: org/codehaus/plexus/util/xml/XmlStreamWriter
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin:2.6
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/2.6/maven-ear-plugin-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/xxx/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.1/plexus-utils-1.1.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------: org.codehaus.plexus.util.xml.XmlStreamWriter
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :SASC-ear
```

Can anyone help me to fix this? I have tried to delete the .m2/repository folder and that is not helpful to solve the issue.

Comment: Are you trying to build an existing library? If so, which one? If not, post your `pom.xml`.

Comment: pom file is too long to put it here. We are trying to build the existing project and tried to add the dependencies to pom.xml and still get the same error. please advice.